Book or story about a lonely man who orders and falls in love with a customized android after his wife passed away and his son went to college
The story focuses on a man who is lonely after his wife passed away and his son went to college. He orders a customized android, but I think he makes it look different from his wife, and they go out together, with them falling in love. The man meets his son at the son's college, and while he has some reservations about the relationship, he relents, saying that his father deserves to be happy. There's also a scene on a train or hyperloop type of transport -- I think it might have been an Amtrak hyper train -- and a line about seeing windmills off the coast.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a novel, novella or short story?  Where and when did you read this?

It was likely between 2013 and 2015, it was on a Nook, so it might have been some kind of exclusive. Based on how long it was, it might have been a short story
